# Removing Activity From the Stack

Tags: android

I have 2 activities, normally I open activity A which then opens activity B.

In the case that a user clicks on a notification and the application is not running at all then B opens first. However when the users clicks the up/actionbackHome button the user should be taken back to A. I have done this by overwritting the up/actionbarHome button and starting activity A and calling finish on B. This works fine as if the user clicks back they exit the app as normal.

The problem is after that, when the user selects this task from the task manager, activity B opens. How can I ensure activity A opens in this case?

**Edit**

So I think the problem is that when I exist the app after I opened it via a notification, the app is still in the task manager. So if I enter the app via the task manager it starts it up in the same way it did from the notification. How do I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

Clear the backstack and return to A

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(B.this,A.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);//clear top of stack.
    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
    return;
}
```